# DelegateCommand<T> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am adding a new Button with functionality to a large existing WPF client application. The Button `Command` should fire a method on the view model through a `DelegateCommand<T>`. The problem is that the whole application crashes on start, apparently because of this `DelegateCommand<T>`. My code is as follows.

### BaseFormViewModel (inherited by PensionTakerViewModel)

```
public DelegateCommand<DocumentType> AddFileCommand { get; private set; }

public BaseFormViewModel(...)
{
    this.AddFileCommand = new DelegateCommand<DocumentType>(this.ExecuteAddFileCommand);
}

protected virtual void ExecuteAddFileCommand(DocumentType documentType)
{
  // Do something...
}
```

### PensionTakerView

```
<ctrl:ErrorDecorator Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <ComboBox AutomationProperties.AutomationId="cmbDocumentType" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.DocumentTypes, ElementName=Root}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
              SelectedValuePath="Value"
              SelectedValue="{Binding DocumentType}"/>
</ctrl:ErrorDecorator>
                
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Tilføj fil" 
        Command="{Binding ViewModel.AddFileCommand, ElementName=Root}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding DocumentType}"/>
```

Now the application is crashing on start and the interesting part of the stack trace is as follows (I have anonymized customer names and terms). Sorry for the small sized image.
[image]

I am quite new to both WPF and MVVM, so it's a bit of a learning curve for me. But from what I understand, it is complaining about the second parameter of the `DelegateCommand<T>` which is the `CanExecute` method. But `DelegateCommand<T>` also has a constructor which only takes one parameter - the `Execute` method. So why is it complaining over this?

I have tried also passing in a `CanExecute` method which just returns true. But the application is still crashing with the same error.

This same use of `DelegateCommand<T>` is existing several places in the application with the same syntax and signature with no problems. So this really shouldn't be an issue.

I have also tried using an `ICommand` and having the `ExecuteAddFileCommand` without parameters. This works for me, but is obviously not a solution as I need to pass a `DocumentType`.

Can someone please help me get further towards a solution?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the code for `DelegateCommand<T>`, really.

Comment: Do you still get an exception if you change the type to `DelegateCommand<object>`?

Comment: @mm8 But then the code probably won't compile because the delegate type won't match.

Comment: @mm8 Actually no.. I changed the type to object and it works. At least the application is not crashing. But now the parameter on ExecuteAddFileCommand() is null. Even though I have selected a value in the combobox, which then should bind to the DocumentType property on the view model.

Comment: So what is `DocumentType` that you are trying to bind to? Does this property actually return a `DocumentType`?

Comment: Let me guess, `DocumentType` is a value type (probably an enum)? In that case, if your command receives a null parameter, the cast will throw that exception.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel yes DocumentType is an enum.

Comment: Okay, well, then it's obvious: the `CommandParameter` binding evaluates to null, and `DelegateCommand<T>` attempts to cast its parameter to `T`. Casting null to a value type will throw an exception.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Okay so what you mean is that my `DocumentType` property that `CommandParameter` binds to does not get the selected value from the combobox and thus passes null to the `DelegateCommand`?

Comment: @RonRonDK: Seems likely. Did you read my answer?

Comment: If you just instantiate the viewmodel does it error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the command parameter is something else than a `DocumentType` object.

If you change the type of the command to `DelegateCommand<object>` you should avoid getting the exception.

Then you could put a breakpoint in your `ExecuteAddFileCommand` method to determine the actual type of the parameter and whether it has been set at all. If not, check your `DocumentType` source property that you bind the `CommandParameter` to:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding DocumentType}"
```

It's type must match the type argument of the `DelegateCommand<T>`.

Comment: If it was "something else", you'd get an `InvalidCastException`. The behaviour suggest the parameter is `null` and `DocumentType` is not a reference type.

Comment: `null` is clearly "something else" than an actual value of some type, isn't it?

Comment: By that I mean that a null value has some interesting implications unlike passing an unrelated type. Is it a default value? A fallback value? Is the binding failing? If anything it narrows down the possibility space.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: What part of the answer do you claim to be wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, I was merely adding to that, no need to be so defensive.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why the type should be `object` to avoid the exception. Is that because the command parameter is not of type `DocumentType`?

Comment: `object` works for (almost) every type.  That's why I suggested you to try with this. Once you have figured things out you should then change back the actual type which apparently is `Nullable<DocumentType>` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked further into this today, going with @mm8's theory that my `CommandParameter` was not of type `DocumentType`. So I followed the `DocumentType` all the way through and found that some places it was nullable, and other places it was not. And once I changed my `CommandParameter` to type `DocumentType?`, the application stopped crashing. My incoming parameter in `ExecuteAddFileCommand()` was still `null` though. And that was ofcourse because I had to include the parameter in the `DelegateCommand<T>`. So the working code looks like this.

### BaseFormViewModel (inherited by PensionTakerViewModel)

```
public DelegateCommand<DocumentType?> AddFileCommand { get; private set; }

public BaseFormViewModel(...)
{
    this.AddFileCommand = new DelegateCommand<DocumentType?>(param => this.ExecuteAddFileCommand(param));
}

protected virtual void ExecuteAddFileCommand(DocumentType? documentType)
{
  // Do something...
}
```

Comment: So why didn't you accept or upvoted my answer?

Comment: @mm8 Your answer helped me get further, but wasn't the direct solution to the problem. So I'm actually not sure whether to accept it as the answer according to SO rules?

Comment: What makes you say that changing the type argument  wasn't "a direct solution to the problem"...?

Comment: @mm8 You're right.. I have accepted your answer. Thanks for your help.